# HTTP Post Unauthorized error on Logic app HTTP

Tags: azure-logic-apps

[image]

[image]

When i'm trig to post xml file using Logic app HTTP connector, its getting error as an Unauthorized.

But credentials are correct.Currently that process for i'm using C# client application. according to that application i'm using same credentials but there for have additionally parameter its call 'RecipientID', so i have doubt for authorization error, Could you please guide me how Can i add this API parameter to Logic app HTTP connector. For your reference here with attached screen shot.

[image: Client App]

[image: LogicApp Unauthorized Error]

Comment: Does this API require headers?

Comment: @khan yes this is a header

Comment: That is a very basic error.  What have you tried to resolve it?  Without known what you've tried, any Answer is just a guess.

Comment: @Johns-305 Actually for resolve this issue, i'm added that receipent ID to HTTP connector as a new header key and value. Key -recipientId and Value -EXKUSATST  [link](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/52132071/60398070-c4fc7580-9b71-11e9-94ba-6fdf1c9e36c9.JPG)

Comment: @Johns-305 This new header key and value. add as a additional key, But still same situation

Comment: do you have the source code of your existing app ? If you don't know how to call the ednpoint, it will be hard to figure out

Comment: I can see Sender Id and Password in the screenshot above. What is that used for?

Comment: unless you can make a request to that http resource from postman and show us that it works, then we cant help you at all